# For each loop showing decimal point when I don't want it to

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmathparse

My Code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[timeSlot/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size =1cm}]
        \foreach [count=\x] [evaluate=\x as \xx using \x-1] \val in {J1, J2}
        {
            \node (node\x) [timeSlot] at (\x,0) {\val};
            \node[above] at (node\x.north west) {\xx};
        }
        \node[above] at (node2.north east) {2};
        \draw[ultra thick] (node1.south west) rectangle (node2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is :

[image: Fractional output]

I don't want the decimal point in the above output. I want them to be simply 0,1 and 2. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please can you make your example compilable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way in this case is just to use `int()` to get an integer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[timeSlot/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size =1cm}]
  \foreach [count=\x] [evaluate=\x as \xx using int(\x-1)] \val in {J1, J2}
  {
    \node (node\x) [timeSlot] at (\x,0) {\val};
    \node[above] at (node\x.north west) {\xx};
  }
  \node[above] at (node2.north east) {2};
  \draw[ultra thick] (node1.south west) rectangle (node2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: integers]

Comment: That's great. Could you point me to the documentation of such functions? Are there also functions for Float and/or Double?

Comment: @SomenathSinha It is all in the Ti*k*Z manual. `int detect` is on page 948 of my version or just look in the index. It is with a bunch of similar settings, so see if you find anything else useful.

Answer (score 4):

The `foreach` can be simplified and use an integer (`count=\x`) which doesn't need any conversion to avoid decimals.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[timeSlot/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size =1cm}]
        \foreach [count=\x from 0] \val in {J1, J2}
        {
            \node (node\x) [timeSlot] at (\x,0) {\val};
            \node[above] at (node\x.north west) {\x};
        }
        \node[above] at (node1.north east) {2};
        \draw[ultra thick] (node0.south west) rectangle (node1.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The pgfmanual just said `[count=\x from 0]` (no `start`...).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Ups!. You're right. It was my mistake. I've corrected it.